# How to add new field value to each item in state mapped with a function on render

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

I want to create a checkout page where the basket of a user will be displayed in a table, the website sells service for an item they own. Before paying the user will have to enter an ID for each product that will be serviced.

I will probably have to do this by having an input box for each item in the table. But I don't know how exactly to link the items in the basket with the value from the input box?

I use Redux and MongoDB for state and database.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--keep a list of items, update its value when the input changes, submit that form data when you push the submit button. What's the specific issue?

Comment: Basically for each element in the List I will reproduce with map() I want to have an input box. In that input box a value has to be entered for each item in the list. How can I do that with just a button basically. I want to add for each element in the collection of the database the extra value but with the press of one button not a button for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your idea is good but needs improvement meit